# Reference for Net-SNMP API?

Tags: c, debugging, api, reference, snmp

I'm currently developing a monitoring application for some in-house hardware using net-snmp. I have code that somewhat works, when calling `snmp_pdu_free()` my code segfaults. I am creating the pdu struct with `snmp_create_pdu()`. I would like an API reference to see if I am in fact writing my code correctly, but I haven't been able to find one. The best thing I've found is the tutorials on the net-snmp website, but they aren't much help for determining if my code is correct while I'm debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are MAN pages for net-snmp, try `man snmp-free-pdu`.  If that doesn't help, the source code for 5.3.3 is available to download here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/net-snmp/5.3.3%20source%20code/net-snmp-5.3.3.zip/download

Comment: The man pages don't mention snmp_create_pdu, though the tutorial does mention it and the sources reference it.

Answer (score 5):

The Net-SNMP documentation is not very helpful, unfortunately.  Overall, the API is a bugger to work with, but it does work.

Aside from net-snmp.org and the mailing list, this is the only other useful Net-SNMP related reference I've found useful:

http://www.cuddletech.com/articles/snmp/index.html

Also, sign up for the 'net-snmp-coders' mailing list.  It is very active and you can get feedback directly from the authors of Net-SNMP.

http://www.net-snmp.org/support/mailinglists.html

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

[In the tutorial](http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/toolkit/demoapp/snmpdemoapp.c), they don't call `snmp_free_pdu()` to delete the PDU created with `snmp_create_pdu()`.
Instead, they call it to delete the one returned by `snmp_synch_response()`.

Indeed, it's [stated in the comments](http://www.net-snmp.org/dev/agent/session__api_8h_source.html#l00048):

> The pdu is freed by snmp_send() unless a failure occured.

I personally think that it's an awkward design decision, but it's too late now.